# What are Context class SychronizationContext class in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I am new to C# multithreading and I am following some tutorial on multithreading, asynchronous programming and parallel programming, where I came across to certain terms like, "Context", "context switching" and "continuation to the original context". After looking into the .NET documentation, I found some similar classes and properties in System.Threading namespace, such as the "CurrentContext" which returns a Context type data and there is "SynchronizationContext" class in the System.Threading namespace.

Can anyone please explain me this terms, properties and the classes? I am finding it hard to grasp.

Thank You.

Comment: The only class or property named "CurrentContext" I can find is the [`System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.CurrentContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.licensemanager.currentcontext) property, which is not in the `System.Threading` namespace. Can you include the fully qualified name of this class or property you are referring to?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, I am giving you the links, have a look.

Comment: Thread class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?view=netframework-4.8#properties

Thread.CurrentContext property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.currentcontext?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Thread_CurrentContext

SynchronizationContext class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: The [`Thread.CurrentContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.currentcontext) property is not available in .NET Core. This is why it didn't pop up when I searched for "CurrentContext" in the Object Browser of my VS. This property returns an object of type `System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context`. I guess it is used by the Remoting infrastructure, to facilitate [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SynchronizationContext` is an older API intended to allow multiple threads to co-ordinate with each other. In particular, this historically comes from the world of UIs like winforms, where there is a primary UI thread, and if you have background work going on, it may need to get *back* to the UI thread in order to perform operations like UI updates. There are multiple mechanisms to do this, and `SynchronizationContext` is one of them. Essentially, this exposes two APIs: `Post` and `Send` (the main difference being that `Send` blocks waiting for the work to be completed).

Now, completely separately to that, `async`/`await` is a *different* API model for performing asynchronous code, i.e.

```cs
var foo = await BarAsync();`
SomethingElse(foo);
```

Here, if `BarAsync` completes synchronously, the code just keeps running normally and `SomethingElse` is executed immediately; but if `BarAsync` returns *incomplete* - i.e. asynchronously - then the thread *unwinds*, returning control to where-ever it came from, and a *continuation* is hooked that will run the `SomethingElse` *when the result from `BarAsync` becomes available*.

Where these two models intersect is that the implementation behind `await` is aware of the existence of `SynchronizationContext`, and *if one exists*, it will (by default) capture the sync-context that existed at the time, and resume execution via that sync-context (`Post`), on the basis that you *probably* want to be back in that threading model, rather than on the thread model of whatever triggered `BarAsync`'s completion. This behavior can be configured (disabled) by using `ConfigureAwait`:

```cs
var foo = await BarAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);`
SomethingElse(foo);
```

Now it will *not* capture the sync-context, and when the incomplete operation resumes no extra indirection will be invoked. This is useful for avoiding an extra context switch, but means that some things (such as updating a UI) may fail. Typically (but not universally), application code *rarely* uses `ConfigureAwait`, and library *usually* uses `ConfigureAwait`.